# MS Bot Framework Sandwich Bot showing JSON on Command Line

Tags: c#, json, frameworks, bots, botframework

I am using Microsoft's Bot Framework and following their tutorial (using C# for the .NET version) on building a [Simple Sandwich Bot](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html#simpleSandwichBot)

I have managed to get the simple version of the bot working, however, when I go to interact with the bot at any of the stages that are of type `enum`, the response from the bot is displayed in JSON format (unlike the plain English that the example shows) - can anyone help me on this one? I am using the Command Line version of the emulator as the ClickOnce emulator has issues with proxy authentication on the network I am on.

I am using the default code provided on the website:-

Sandwich.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
#pragma warning disable 649
// The SandwichOrder is the simple form you want to fill out.  It must be serializable so the bot can be stateless.
// The order of fields defines the default order in which questions will be asked.
// Enumerations shows the legal options for each field in the SandwichOrder and the order is the order values will be presented 
// in a conversation.
namespace Microsoft.Bot.Sample.SimpleSandwichBot
{
    public enum SandwichOptions
    {
        BLT, BlackForestHam, BuffaloChicken, ChickenAndBaconRanchMelt, ColdCutCombo, MeatballMarinara,
        OvenRoastedChicken, RoastBeef, RotisserieStyleChicken, SpicyItalian, SteakAndCheese, SweetOnionTeriyaki, Tuna,
        TurkeyBreast, Veggie
    };
    public enum LengthOptions { SixInch, FootLong };
    public enum BreadOptions { NineGrainWheat, NineGrainHoneyOat, Italian, ItalianHerbsAndCheese, Flatbread };
    public enum CheeseOptions { American, MontereyCheddar, Pepperjack };
    public enum ToppingOptions
    {
        Avocado, BananaPeppers, Cucumbers, GreenBellPeppers, Jalapenos,
        Lettuce, Olives, Pickles, RedOnion, Spinach, Tomatoes
    };
    public enum SauceOptions
    {
        ChipotleSouthwest, HoneyMustard, LightMayonnaise, RegularMayonnaise,
        Mustard, Oil, Pepper, Ranch, SweetOnion, Vinegar
    };
    [Serializable]
    public class SandwichOrder
    {
        public SandwichOptions? Sandwich;
        public LengthOptions? Length;
        public BreadOptions? Bread;
        public CheeseOptions? Cheese;
        public List<ToppingOptions> Toppings;
        public List<SauceOptions> Sauce;
        public static IForm<SandwichOrder> BuildForm()
        {
            return new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
                    .Message("Welcome to the simple sandwich order bot!")
                    .Build();
        }
    };
}
```

MessageController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ProperBot
{
    [BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// POST: api/Messages
        /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
        /// </summary>
        internal static IDialog<SandwichOrder> MakeRootDialog()
        {
            return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(SandwichOrder.BuildForm))
                .Do(async (context, order) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var completed = await order;
                        // Actually process the sandwich order...
                        await context.PostAsync("Processed your order!");
                    }
                    catch (FormCanceledException<SandwichOrder> e)
                    {
                        string reply;
                        if (e.InnerException == null)
                        {
                            reply = $"You quit on {e.Last}--maybe you can finish next time!";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reply = "Sorry, I've had a short circuit.  Please try again.";
                        }
                        await context.PostAsync(reply);
                    }
                });
        }
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
        {

            if (activity != null)
            {
                // one of these will have an interface and process it
                switch (activity.GetActivityType())
                {
                    case ActivityTypes.Message:
                        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRootDialog);
                        break;
                    case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate:
                    case ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate:           
                    case ActivityTypes.Typing:           
                    case ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData:               
                    default:
                        Trace.TraceError($"Unknown activity type ignored: {activity.GetActivityType()}");
                        break;
                }

            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }

    }
}
```

The response I am receiving:

```
Bot1 said:
 Welcome to the sandwich order bot!
Bot1 said:

[
  {
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
    "content": {
      "text": "What kind of sandwich would you like, eh? ",
      "buttons": [
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "BLT",
          "value": "BLT"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Black Forest Ham",
          "value": "Black Forest Ham"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Buffalo Chicken",
          "value": "Buffalo Chicken"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Chicken And Bacon Ranch Melt",
          "value": "Chicken And Bacon Ranch Melt"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Cold Cut Combo",
          "value": "Cold Cut Combo"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Meatball Marinara",
          "value": "Meatball Marinara"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Oven Roasted Chicken",
          "value": "Oven Roasted Chicken"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Roast Beef",
          "value": "Roast Beef"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Rotisserie Style Chicken",
          "value": "Rotisserie Style Chicken"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Spicy Italian",
          "value": "Spicy Italian"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Steak And Cheese",
          "value": "Steak And Cheese"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Sweet Onion Teriyaki",
          "value": "Sweet Onion Teriyaki"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Tuna",
          "value": "Tuna"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Turkey Breast",
          "value": "Turkey Breast"
        },
        {
          "type": "imBack",
          "title": "Veggie",
          "value": "Veggie"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

The response I should be receiving:

```
Please select a sandwich
1. BLT
2. Black Forest Ham
3. Buffalo Chicken
4. Chicken And Bacon Ranch Melt
5. Cold Cut Combo
6. Meatball Marinara
7. Oven Roasted Chicken
8. Roast Beef
9. Rotisserie Style Chicken
10. Spicy Italian
11. Steak And Cheese
12. Sweet Onion Teriyaki
13. Tuna
14. Turkey Breast
15. Veggie
>
```

Please note that I only receive this type of response when the bot is dealing with an `enum` - if the bot is dealing with a `List` type or `string`, then the responses are in plain English.

Comment: looks more like a bug that should be filed at github, although the wise, learned men from MS bot framework team are lurking at stackoverflow too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the console cannot read these types of responses as they are a Microsoft-type response called 'Cards' - applications like Skype, Facebook Messenger and E-mail can read it.